# Solving an AC Circuit Inverter Estimate

Tags: power, inverter, power-engineering, circuit-theory

This is an electric power engineering question not electronic so this circuit doesn't actually solve. I added it for illustration purposes. **Srate = Sout**.

I'm trying to solve this below circuit for **Vg** because I want to calculate the current in the line and potential voltage rise at node "Vg".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFwQo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I write KCL out at the Vg node I get the below set of equations (* is complex conjugate).
[image]

The final equation #9, all variables are known except the magnitude and angle of phasor **Vg**. I need another equation to be able to constrain the phasor angle and magnitude of **Vg** to a solution. Is there a way to solve this circuit for **Vg**? I don't see a KVL equation I could write out to constraint equation 9 and produce a solution for **Vg**. My understanding is that 'grid following' inverter steady state behavior can be approximated by a voltage controlled current source. Is there another constraint I'm missing that would make this solvable?